# Using this Script/formula for to get value for some selected Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This script/formula add two adjacent columns together (Column F & G) and put it in column H for all sheets in the google sheets, I need further assistance in making it calculate only some selected sheets in google sheet.
[image]

```
function runMacro() {
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(addFormula_);
}

function addFormula_(_sh) {    const formulaString = '=Filter(F2:F+G2:G,F2:F<>"")'
  const theAddress = 'H2';
  _sh.getRange(theAddress).setFormula(formulaString);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// By Name - Only Specified Sheets
function runMacro() {

  const includeSheets = [`Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, `Sheet3`, `etc`]

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()
                .filter(sheet => includeSheets.includes(sheet.getName()))
                .forEach(sheet => addFormula_(sheet))

}
```

Comment: @ NEWAZA, Thank you, it works... But on the selected sheets, I don't want it to calculate when the CELL (F2 and G2) is empty, check this link - 
 drive.google.com/file/d/1kRZHYLCncRXZN00SAdE4NUTaEjTjly6p - I don't want the #N/A there, but when F2 and G2 is filled then it should input the Addition in H2. Thank you.

Comment: Hi there @KasimUsman! I have been studying your comment. The main issue is that you don't want to calculate the values of `F2` and `G2`, isn't that true? Those calculations are run on the `addFormula_` function from your question, have you tried modifying it? Also please be aware that you already selected a good answer, so this question is marked as answered.